# Mockable @AppStorage in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, mocking

When developing UIKit apps it's quite easy to mock the `UserDefaults` by defining a protocol and injecting the needed implementation in the `UIViewController`.

```
protocol Defaults {
    var numberOfHandsPlayed: Int { get set }
}

struct AppDefaults: Defaults {
    static let shared = AppDefaults()
    private let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

    struct Keys {
        private init() {}
        static let numberOfHandsPlayed = "numberOfHandsPlayed"
    }


    var numberOfHandsPlayed: Int {
        get {
            userDefaults.integer(forKey: Keys.numberOfHandsPlayed)
        }
        set(numberOfHandsPlayed) {
            userDefaults.setValue(numberOfHandsPlayed, forKey: Keys.numberOfHandsPlayed)
        }
    }
}

struct MockDefaults: Defaults {
    var numberOfHandsPlayed: Int {
    get {
        // mocking behaviour
    }
    set(numberOfHandsPlayed) {
        // mocking behaviour
    }
}

class PracticeViewController: UIViewController {
    private var defaults: Defaults?
    // defaults can be set to MockDefaults or AppDefaults
}
```

But now with SwiftUI I can do the following using the `@AppStorage` property wrapper:

```
@AppStorage("numberOfHandsPlayed") var numberOfHandsPlayed: Int = 3
```

Is there a clean solution in SwiftUI to mock this property wrapper and have the same flexibility as in my UIKit example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AppStorage` allows to specify storage to be used (by default standard `UserDefaults`), so this feature can be utilised for your purpose.

One of possible approaches is to subclass standard user defaults, and mock it later if/where needed.

```
class MyUserDefaults: UserDefaults {
    // override/add anything needed here
}

struct DemoView: View {
    @AppStorage("numberOfHandsPlayed", store: MyUserDefaults()) var numberOfHandsPlayed: Int = 3

   // ... other code
```